# Error 500 when bad password or user logout

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect, error-handling

Since update to version 3.6 when user tries to login with bad password he is not redirected to proper page (did you forget password? for example). Instead he gets an Error 500 message. Also when user logs out, the page isn't properly refreshed and user also gets Error 500. Any ideas what's happening? I can't see any of this errors in error log. A matter of fact I can't see any logs since the update. The path to log and temp seems proper. Tomorrow I am going to test this on my local environment to eliminate any server problems. I'll appreciate any help.

Sincerely, Thomas

Comment: Did you try check user and permissions file and folders?

Comment: Hi @Max, yes I did check the file and folders permissions - I didn't change anything before the update and afterwards. So I did a little more testing and this is happening when the FTP in Joomla global settings is Enabled. When I disable the FTP the log starts to work just fine. I had earlier problems with FTP but I have some components which work with only FTP enabled...

Comment: Oh the bad password redirect works properly but the Logout redirect doesn't, and also gives the Error 500

Answer (score 1):

So this fix helped me with my bad password login problem:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11093/files

and the logout problem still persisted, but after upgrading to 3.6.1 everything works normally. This is not exactly a great answer...

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs - specifically the ModSecurity log. It might be that there is a rule that is triggered when the redirect is taking place.

Also, temporarily disable your .htaccess file and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank You @itoctopus for Your time. After update to 3.6.1 everything works. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your logout redirection, make sure to also check your Joomla login module, if you are using menu items, make sure they are going to active links. I used to use the default settings, but have found setting active menu items seem to work a little better.